# Java 16 DateTimeFormatter parsing issue

Tags: java, localdatetime, datetimeformatter

I am trying to parse date

```
final LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-01-17 09:28:45", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'Z'"));
```

Im expecting LocalDateTime because this last 'Z' should not impact as it is in single quotes.

BTW following code is working

```
final LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-01-17 09:28:45", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? What do you want with that 'Z'???

Comment: Indeed - why do you have a Z in your pattern when it's not in the value you're parsing?

Comment: If your string might end with `Z`, why don’t you simply remove the `Z` before parsing?

Answer (score 1):

> Im expecting LocalDateTime because this last 'Z' should not impact as
> it is in single quotes.

the `Z` can be ignored if you put it between brackets like this:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss['Z']"
```

The single quotes can not ignore but we use them to define a static parts like the `Z` in your case.

**Note** that the `LocalDateTime` not have zone part.